# How to configure and compile ArangoDB with already installed v8

Tags: arangodb, embedded-v8

I am trying to compile ArandoDB 2.2.3 in my Cubietruck board runing Debian for armhf
Since 3rdParty V8 will not compile and will throw error "#error Target architecture ia32 is only supported on ia32 host", I decided to install libv8-dev, so my system have all the headers and libs I need for ArangoDB. How do I tell ArangoDB configure utility to use the present v8 headers and lib files?

```
./configure --disable-all-in-one-v8 --with-v8=/usr --with-v8-lib=/usr/lib --enable-all-in-one-libev --enable-all-in-one-icu
```

did not work, got this error:

...

```
configure: CHECKING FOR GOOGLE V8
configure: --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
checking for v8::V8::GetVersion() in -lv8_base... no
configure: error: Please install the V8 library from Google
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you send me your "config.log"?

Comment: yes sure! [here it is the link](http://pastebin.com/4ruQqy1w) thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think v8 is shipped in different versions on different operation systems, and the libraries may also have different names. Our configure script tries to create an example program and links against v8_base and v8_nosnapshot. If the v8 library on your system is just libv8.so, then this won't work.

The following workaround should do it:

```
# go to where libraries are installed
cd /usr/lib 

# create symlinks to libv8.so
sudo ln -s libv8.so libv8_base.so
sudo ln -s libv8.so libv8_snapshot.so
sudo ln -s libv8.so libv8_nosnapshot.so
```

That might get you past the configure...

However, the V8 API is constantly changing without being downwards-compatible. I therefore think that you will see lots of compile errors if you try compiling ArangoDB against a different version of v8. That's why we decided to bundle the v8 library in the expected version with ArangoDB.

Comment: mm bad luck: 
`checking for v8::V8::GetVersion() in -lv8_base... yes
checking V8 version... 3.8.9.20
configure: error: V8 version found is too low: 3.8.9.20. Please install V8 with version 3.16.0 or higher or use the option --enable-all-in-one-v8.` I guess I will try to compile the one that comes with ArangoDB. Thanks anyway.